# BoundsLocatorException running testfx in headless mode

Tags: javafx, headless, bounds, testfx

I'm running some TestFx test cases that work fine in my local for headless mode and headful mode but for some reason when the same test runs in jenkins in headless mode only I receive the following message on lines where some buttons are clicked.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.testfx.service.locator.BoundsLocatorException: bounds are not visible in Scene

Does anyone know why this would happen?

These are my headless properties....

```
testfx.robot", "glass"
"testfx.headless", "true"
prism.order", "sw"
prism.text", "t2k"
headless.geometry", "1600x1200-32
```

Answer (score 1):

So my issue was caused by Jenkins having a different screen size and I was able to avoid the exceptions by hard coding the application dimensions when running in Jenkins